# abelian extension of local fields tamely ramified iff 1+m killed by Artin map

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

In Milne's notes on Class Field Theory, I.1.9, there is the following claim stated without proof:

> Suppose $L/K$ is a finite abelian extension of local fields, and let
>   $\phi_K:K^\times\to Gal(L/K)$ be the local artin map, which is
>   surjective with kernel $Nm(L^\times)$. Then $L/K$ is tamely ramified
>   iff $1+\mathfrak{m}_K\subset Nm(L^\times)$.

I can prove one direction: consider the composition $K^\times/Nm(L^\times)\to Gal(L/K)\to Gal(l/k)$, where $l,k$ are the residue fields; let $p$ be the residue characteristic. The first map is an isomorphism, and if $L/K$ is tamely ramified then the second map is surjective with kernel having order prime to $p$. Now if $\alpha\in 1+\mathfrak{m}_K$, then $\alpha^{p^n}\in 1+\mathfrak{m}_K^{n+1}$ (prove by induction on $n$), and so for large $n$ we have $\alpha^{p^n}=1$ in $K^\times/Nm(L^\times)$. On the other hand, $\alpha$ is a unit, so it maps to 1 in $Gal(l/k)$, and hence by hypothesis the order of $\alpha$ is prime to $p$. It follows that in fact $\alpha=1$, so $1+\mathfrak{m}_K\in Nm(L^\times)$.

However, I don't know how to prove the other direction (except when $k=\mathbb{F}_p$ and thus $u^{p-1}\in 1+\mathfrak{m}_K$ for any unit $u$ of $K$). Can someone suggest a proof?

Follow-up: is it true more generally that the conductor of $L/K$ (i.e. smallest $f$ for which $1+\mathfrak{m}_K^f$ is killed by $\phi_K$) is equal to the smallest $f$ for which the higher ramification group $G_f=0$ (where $G_f$ is the subgroup of $\sigma\in Gal(L/K)$ satisfying $|\sigma(\pi_L)-\pi_L|<|\pi_L|^f$)?

Comment: I would assume not (but just because this would save a lot of work) has he already shown that the ramification filtration correspondends to the filtration $1+\mathfrak{m}_K^i$?

Comment: No -- there have been no proofs up to this point. But do you have an alternate reference for this? I would hope that we could deduce this just from the defining properties of the local artin map. (But in any case I think it should follow from Lubin-Tate theory...)